# Which library should I use to communicate with serial port on Java ME?

Tags: java-me, serial-port

I have some devices with Linux embedded and need to program a producer thread...

Thinking of doing it with JME, which library is the best to access serial port on this scenario?

Comment: Serial ports are files, aren't they? You can just use the relevant java.nio.* classes. Or do you also need to actually configure the serial port as well?

Comment: I just need to capture all string data getting into the port, and send some data through the port as well

Comment: (http://serialio.com/support/jspCommAPI.php) this is the relevant link  I could suggest.

Comment: @Milox well then you may try and use a `Selector` on the device file, it might just work! Well, if you know what the device file is named, of course...

Comment: @Milox, any breakthroughs on this ?

Comment: found this but haven't tested, http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/j2me_http.phtml

Comment: what you want to do by accessing serial port of mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CommConnection from a JME app to read/write data from/to a serial port. http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/CommConnection.html

For example

```
CommConnection cc = (CommConnection) Connector.open("comm:com0;baudrate=19200");
```

Before calling `Connector.open` you should check which serial ports are available with

```
String ports = System.getProperty("microedition.commports");
```